Delegate function not being called when tapping a poi using the gms and swift ui
So I implemented the google maps sdk in swiftui and for some reason the the delegate function mapView(_:didTapPOIWithPlaceID:name:location:) is not being called, but the function func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) is. I am tapping pois. So I really do not now what I'm doing wrong.
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     let options = GMSMapViewOptions()
     options.frame = self.view.bounds;
        
     let mapView = GMSMapView(options:options)
     mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
     mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
     mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
     mapView.delegate = self
     self.view.addSubview(mapView)
     self.mapView = mapView

}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapPOIWithPlaceID placeID: String, name: String, location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        // Not being called
        infoMarker.snippet = placeID
        infoMarker.position = location
        infoMarker.title = name
        infoMarker.opacity = 0;
        infoMarker.infoWindowAnchor.y = 1
        infoMarker.map = mapView
        mapView.selectedMarker = infoMarker
        
    }
      


Could you please provide us with a sample demo using this?

@rafon I'm using swiftui and these demos are made for uikit. So I don't know how useful that would be.

I've had the same issue while using Maps SDK 9.0.0 and reverting back to 8.4.0 resolved it. It seems to be a bug on Google's end. I should probably write them a ticket

Yes I found someone who reported the same issue and going back to 8.4.0 resolved it, but thanks for the help.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

You are aware of the need for the commenting privilege, which you do not have. You know the rule ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). In that situation, please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism, an answering post, for what it is not meant for and which you are not yet allowed to do. However, this special case I think can be accepted as an answer.
